# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/oo_20161031-6508-1bswvam/roo_workbook.xml in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I am using gem **roo**. Here I am getting the error as

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /tmp/oo_20161031-6508-1bswvam/roo_workbook.xml

My model coding is,

```
  def self.import(file)
spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
header = spreadsheet.row(1)
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  subject = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
  subject.attributes = row.to_hash
  subject.save!
end
```

end

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xml" then Roo::XML.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
end
```

end

It takes the parameters as,

```
"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mk8vcsZQSd0YvjxM1EOQB8IYlyf6hDgAC/FE8lgGDElbkaPIjtiCNGEynsjfh1KklHErjp+aWWuDzVOZah8PVA==", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0055a570f4f8d8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161031-6508-18g6ask.xlsx>, @original_filename="TEST.xlsx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"TEST.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n">, "commit"=>"Import"
```

Error indicates in open file format. What is the correct solution for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with new file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error arises when the excel file saved wrongly. This makes the puzzle, to open the file by the app. So check with excel save or path or version , is the solution for this issue.